# When trying to count distinct values I have an error " Every derived table must have its own alias "

Tags: mysql

When trying to count distinct values I have an error:

> Every derived table must have its own alias

my query :

```
select count(*) as user from (select distinct user_type from userValidation);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add an alias for the subquery:

```
select count(*) as user from (select distinct user_type from userValidation) t
```

but you can get the same results without the subquery:

```
select count(distinct user_type)  as user from userValidation
```